# Category list is not loaded in the recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working with an application in android studio. The categories list is not getting data or loading data and appeared empty.
The problem could be in my java code, I just couldn't find it.

.................... 
This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:background="#f5f5f5">


  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/category_recyclerview"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#1976d2"
      android:elevation="3dp"

      android:visibility="visible"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_recyclerview">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_page_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />



  </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/retry_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:text="Retry"
      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPurble"
      android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
      android:translationZ="8dp"
      android:stateListAnimator="@null"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the fragment_home java code :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private NetworkInfo networkInfo;

    public static   SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Button retryBtn;

    public ImageView noInternetConnection;
    private HomePageAdapter adapter;

    private RecyclerView homePageRecyclerView;

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        categoryRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_recyclerview);
        homePageRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_page_recyclerview);
        noInternetConnection = view.findViewById(R.id.no_internet_connection);
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        retryBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.retry_btn);

            retryBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            categoryRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            homePageRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager((getActivity()));
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            //we will import the categories from the DBqueries Class ...loadCategorries function
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categoryModelList);
            categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

            if (categoryModelList.size() == 0){
                loadCategories(categoryAdapter,getContext());
            }else {
                categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            LinearLayoutManager testingLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager((getContext()));
            testingLayoutManger.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            homePageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(testingLayoutManger);
            //we import the homePageList from the the DBqueries

            if (lists.size() == 0){
                loadedCategoriesNames.add("HOME");
                lists.add(new ArrayList<HomePageModel>());
                adapter =new HomePageAdapter(lists.get(0));
                loadFragmentData(adapter,getContext(),0,"HOME");
            }else {
                adapter = new HomePageAdapter(lists.get(0));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            homePageRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //// refresh layout

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                reloadPage();

            }
        });

        //// refresh layout

        retryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reloadPage();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void reloadPage(){

        categoryModelList.clear();
        lists.clear();
        loadedCategoriesNames.clear();
        categoryRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            loadCategories(categoryAdapter,getContext());

            loadedCategoriesNames.add("HOME");
            lists.add(new ArrayList<HomePageModel>());

            loadFragmentData(adapter,getContext(),0,"HOME");

    }
}
```

And This the code frim class DBQuries that use to get categories from firebase. I just copied the code related to categories

```
public class DBqueries {

        //Identifying Current User
        public static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        public static FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        public static FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        public static List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();


        public static  List<List<HomePageModel>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        public static List<String> loadedCategoriesNames = new ArrayList<>();
        public static List<String> wishList = new ArrayList<>();


        public static void loadCategories(final CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter, final Context context ){


        firebaseFirestore.collection("CATEGORIES").orderBy("index").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                                categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel(documentSnapshot.get("icon").toString(),documentSnapshot.get("categoryName").toString()));
                            }
                            categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(context,error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Could it be that the RecyclerView has height set to wrap_content in the xml? And no bottom constraint.

Comment: @Isak I updated the question with detail of the problem. The problem is not with the xml file because it was working before I change the java code .

Comment: do you successfully receive data from firebase ?

Comment: Yes. everything except Categories. @Zain